# Команда java не работает когда подключен пакет

Tags: java, package, javac

К примеру есть такой код:

```
package com.company;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

Этот код я написал в intelliJ IDEA и он, соответсвенно, подключил для себя пакет `com.company`, затем я зашел в терминал и скомпилировал этот файл *`javac Main.java`*, после, без каких-либо ошибок создался *Main.class*. И теперь, когда я выполняю команду *`java Main`* *(запуск созданного файла байт-кода)*, в терминале выдается ошибка **`Error: Could not find or load main class Main`**
. Если же убрать подключенный `com.company`, то все нормально и он выводит `Hello world`. Я не понимаю **почему если подключить пакет `com.company`, скомпилировать и попробовать запустить файл байт-кода (java Main) в терминале выдается ошибка `Error: Could not find or load main class Main` ?**

Comment: пишите `java com.company.Main`  при запуске

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Важно:

1. Обращаться к классу по полному имени (которое включает пакет)
2. Запускать из текущего каталога проекта (в данном случае тот каталог внутри которого лежит папка com)
3. Правильнее использовать параметр classpath

Answer (score 1):

Запустите в терминале из каталога , в котором находится файл:

```
java -classpath . YourFile
```